# Contradiction on natural number's zero test

Tags: coq

I have a natural number that is not equal to zero. I want to prove that if it is equal to zero then it give false.

```
Lemma notzero : 
  forall n, 
    n <> 0 ->
    n =? 0 = false.
Proof.
  intro n. inversion H.
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using inversion in every proof, I find that the proofs are more maintainable in the long run if you use boolean reflection.  The libraries have many useful lemmas that you can use, they often are called something with "reflect", "decide", "dec" or "spec" as in specification, so you can i.e. search for lemmas related to `<` with `Search (_ < _) "spec".`

The reflection lemmas are designed to at the same time 1) destruct the boolean term in your proof context, and 2) add the corresponding `Prop` to your context, making it easy to then use `lia`, `omega`, etc. to finish the proof.

In your case, you can use `Nat.eq_spec` (from `Require Import PeanoNat.`).  Do

```
destruct (Nat.eq_spec n 0).
```

It will create two branches, in one `n ?= 0` is replaced with `true` and `n=0` is added to the context, and in the other `n =? 0` is replaced with `false` and `n<>0` is added to the context.  It is now very easy to finish of the proof, as the first goal's context contains the contradiction `n=0` and `n<>0`, and the second goal is `false=false`.  You can use the automation tactical `now`, so the complete proof is

```
now destruct (Nat.eq_spec n 0).
```

If you want to use integers `Z`, instead, the proof becomes `now destruct (Z.eq_spec n 0).`. as the `Z` module has many of the corresponding lemmas with matching names.

Comment: Note: This is just an elaboration on @Théo's answer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using now when learning how to do proofs. I would never use it really, as it can be slow and it's not always clear how it finds a proof, but that's more of a personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use the fact that `=?` reflects equality on natural numbers (`Nat.eqb_spec`).
Are you using the two notions of equality on purpose?
Note that `n <> 0` is a notation for `n = 0 -> False`.

```
Lemma notzero : 
  forall n, 
    n <> 0 ->
    n =? 0 = false.
Proof.
  intros n h. destruct (Nat.eqb_spec n 0).
  - exfalso. apply h. assumption.
  - reflexivity.
Qed.
```

There is also the possibility of simply doing an analysis on `n`.
If it is `0` then you can use your hypothesis to conclude, and if it is some `S m` then your goal will be provable by `reflexivity`.

```
Lemma notzero : 
  forall n, 
    n <> 0 ->
    n =? 0 = false.
Proof.
  intros n h. destruct n.
  - contradiction.
  - reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: I have solved the lemma like this,
Lemma  da:forall n:nat,
n <> 0 ->n=0-> False.
Proof.
  intros n eq1 eq2. apply eq1.  apply eq2.  
Is this is ok.

Comment: So you changed the lemma to use `=` instead of `=?`. Do you know the difference between the two? Also, is your problem solved by @larsr's or my answer? If so you should accept the corresponding one.

Comment: Use = for natural numbers equality and use =? when equality give bool.
This does not solve the problem. According to your reply I 
Import Nat.eqb_spec.
Intros n H. destruct n
+ apply H.
+ reflexivity.
But ,when I import Nat.eqb_spec.Error message comes(i.e
Nat.eqb_spec is not a module).

Comment: As suggested by Mr.larsr ,I started the proof  in this way
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Nat.eq_spec.
Proof.
Intros n H.
destruct (Nat.eq_spec n 0).
Then error message is ” Cannot find a physical path bound to logical
path matching suffix Nat”.

Comment: `Nat.eqb_spec` is not a module indeed, so you do not need to `Require` or `Import`. Just use `destruct (Nat.eqb_spec n 0)`.

Comment: After destruct (Nat.eqb_spec n 0).I applied lemma eqb_eq. Still I have no H to prove first  subgoal(true=false).
Variable A : Set.
Require Import Arith.
Require Import PeanoNat.
Search  Nat.eqb_spec.
Theorem eqb_eq p q : (p =? q) = true <-> p=q.
Proof. Admitted. 
Lemma notzero : 
  forall n, 
    n <> 0 ->
    n =? 0 = false.
Proof.
intros n H.
destruct (Nat.eqb_spec n 0).
+ unfold not in H .  apply eqb_eq.
+ reflexivity.
In hypothesis  ,l have
n : nat
H : n = 0 -> False
e : n = 0
Goal:  true = false

Comment: I edited my answer to include the solutions. You do have enough to prove `true = false` in that you have a contradiction in your hypotheses (`n = 0` and `n <> 0`).

Comment: After using destruct (Nat.eqb_spec n 0). 
+  subst. eauto.
In hypothesis I have
H : 0 <> 0
Goal:  true = false
How apply H to solve the goal?

Comment: Thank you .Thank u for your time and help. By applying contradiction i have solve it . Can you give some example in explaining the difference between n=0 and n=?0. Or some reference material.

Comment: `n = 0` comes from the inductive definition of equality: you can prove `x = x` for any `x`, and that's pretty much it. `n =? 0` is defined by pattern-matching: `0 = 0` *reduces* to `true`, and `S n =? S m` *reduces* to `n =? m`.